# Hardcoding a Windows path and escaping the backslashes

Tags: c#, webforms, path

I am trying to use Path.Combine to create a path in C#.

```
string documentPath = "C:\\myApps\\Application1\\Documents\\Project\\"
string projectName = "Project1"
string combinedPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentPath, projectName)
```

**In the end combinedPath looks like the following:** `C:\\myApps\\Application1\\Documents\\Project\\Project1`
I would expect the additional backslashes to escape the ones that I actually need so my combined path looks normal without double backslashes in it.

**UPDATE:**
I think I was getting tricked by the debugger the entire time. Can someone confirm that the debugger will always show a string that has \'s in it as \\

Comment: You are validating your result by inspecting the debugger, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of escape sequence `\\` you can simply use `@` `Verbatim literal` as used in examples.

**Method one : Have weaknesses**

You may use `+` string Concatenation ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx))

```
string documentPath = @"C:\myApps\Application1\Documents\Project\";
string projectName = "Project1";

string fullpath = documentPath + projectName;

Console.WriteLine(fullpath);
```

**Method two : Recommended way**

Once you use `@`Verbatim literal, you can simply use `Path.Combine()`

```
Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.Combine(documentPath,projectName));
```

As pointed in comments and other answers, using `Path.Combine()` is the better approach.

Output :

```
C:\myApps\Application1\Documents\Project\Project1 // <= From + concatenation 
C:\myApps\Application1\Documents\Project\Project1 // <= From path Combine
```

**Additionally** : Escape sequence representation ([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx))

**String Escape Sequences**

> At compile time, verbatim strings are converted to ordinary strings
>   with all the same escape sequences. Therefore, if you view a verbatim
>   string in the debugger watch window, you will see the escape
>   characters that were added by the compiler, not the verbatim version
>   from your source code. For example, the verbatim string
>   @"C:\files.txt" will appear in the watch window as C:\\files.txt.

Comment: Concatenation will apply a new instance to memory every time your `fullpath` would be altered.  Also it lacks the expressive nature of `Path.Combine` to indicate two directory or directory paths are merging.  Also it is harder to troubleshoot in some instances, rather then just see how it was combined `Path.Combine(demo, example);` and applying breakpoint you have to hunt for the concatenated implementation.

Comment: Err I think I was getting tricked by the debugger the entire time. Can someone confirm that the debugger will always show a string that has \'s in it as \\

Comment: @user2272527 yes, that's how escape character \ is interpreted

Comment: _"Why not simply use + string Concatenation"_ - because you can't always control input. If `documentPath = @"C:\myApps\Application1\Documents\Project";` (without trailing backslash), the `+` approach will make the final path `C:\myApps\Application1\Documents\ProjectProject1`.

Comment: @CodeCaster yes I noted that and included in the answer and I will try to emphasis the weakness more soon with an edit

Answer (score 2):

You can do this several different ways, however if we utilize your current approach your combined `Path.Combine` will output the proper path.

```
var path = "C:\\Example\\";
var dir = "Demo";
var combine = Path.Combine(path, dir);

//Output:
C:\Example\Demo
```

Another approach would be to simply use the `@` operator, it will alleviate any requirement of backslashes when you create your original path.  So instead of the above, you would have:

```
var path = @"C:\Example";
```

Then when you do your `Path.Combine` the code will work as intended as well.  The only approach I would say to avoid is concatenation.

- Concatenation: Creates a new instance in memory, every time implemented.
- Concatenation: The code can be difficult to troubleshoot (Especially if you make an error somewhere), as the combining of the paths isn't nearly as expressive to see.

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
string documentPath = @"C:\myApps\Application1\Documents\Project";
string projectName = "Project1";
string combinedPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentPath, projectName);
```